# what does separable convex program mean?

Tags: convex-optimization

In literature,a separable program is formulated like this:

$$\min_{x_{1},...x_{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_{i}(x_{i})$$

where $f_{i}$ is a closed proper convex function.

My question is what does 'closed' mean? and is the following problem separable?

$$\min_{X \in R^{mn}}||X||_{*}+\lambda||\mathcal AX-b||_{2}^{2}$$

Comment: This may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_convex_function

Comment: I think you are misreading the "literature". The functions $f_i$ do *not* have to be closed, proper, or convex for the problem to be separable. Separability is a distinct property from the others. Of course, a separable *convex* function will require convexity of each $f_i$. But again, that's a distinct property. I could easily conceive of a separable non-convex function.

Comment: And no, your problem is not separable, because the two terms involve the same variable.

Answer (score 1):

A convex function is called closed **iff** $f = \operatorname{cl} f$,
where $\operatorname{cl} f$ is defined as follows:
If $f(x) = -\infty$ for any $x$, then $(\operatorname{cl} f)(x) = -\infty$
for all $x$, otherwise $\operatorname{cl} f$ is the function whose epigraph is
given by the $\overline{\operatorname{epi} f}$.

Since the $f$ in the question is proper,the function is closed **iff** the epigraph is closed **iff** the function is lower semicontinuous.

Without knowing what $\|\cdot\|_*$ is, it is difficult to give conditions under which the problem might be separable.

Comment: That is the nuclear norm---the sum of the singular values of $X$.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: Thanks Michael!

Comment: what does \bar{epi f} mean here?

Comment: @QinshengZhang It is the closure of the epigraph of $f$.